# How do I end a service only when I exit the app?

Tags: android, android-service, android-lifecycle, ondestroy

I have a service I want to run the second the app opens, and only want this service to end as soon as the user exits the app. How do I program those two things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use StartService in onCreate of the activity 
and in onexit button onclicklistener use stopService

Comment: I do not see the onExit method in the list of Override/Implement Methods list provided by Eclipse

Comment: I don't think that method even exists

Comment: you can have exit button in ur activity and when exit is clicked u can stop the service

Comment: there is no onExit method, iam suggesting u to create on exit button in ur activity and in onclicklistener of that button u can stop the service

Answer (score 1):

use can use [Activity.onUserInteraction ()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onUserInteraction%28%29) for Stopping service when user press Back button as:

```
@Override
    public void onUserInteraction()
    {
        super.onUserInteraction();
        //stop your service here
    }
```

and second solution is  you can also use onKeyDown or onBackPresed for stopping service on user back-pressed:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
    //stop your service here
    return true;
}
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

handle Back Pressed :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
//stop your service here
return;
}
```

Comment: this onUserInteraction applies for when the user hits which button, or when they use the touchscreen or what?

Comment: onUserInteraction  method called when user Pressed backbutton on your application. you can also use onKeyDown or onBackPressed for stoping Service instead of  onUserInteraction

Comment: i like the back button idea but I will have 2 activities, and on the first activity i want the music to start, and when i switch between the 2 activities i want the music to continue play. I only want the music to stop playing when the user quite to their home screen or turns off their display or quits the app. So the problem here is if you wanted to use the back button to swap between activities, it would end the service, thus ending the music, which I don't want.

Comment: as soon as the app opens the service starts, so my first activity is when the service starts

Comment: then override Backbutton on first Activity from where user is selecting for playing